# A Custom sort of the values within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I am a newbie trying to learn R and I have a data frame like this:

```
  a b c d
a 0 6 2 0
b 1 0 3 0
c 0 0 0 2
d 0 0 0 0
```

I want to sort a dataframe by two actions: 
1. First, find the row which has the maximum TOTAL value and creating this

```
  a b c d  TOTAL
a 0 6 2 0    8
b 1 0 3 0    4
c 0 0 0 2    2
d 0 0 0 0    0
```

2. Second, select the row with the maximum value and recording the crossed 
   value in front of each character from max to min. So it results into a new dataframe like this:

```
    'x'
a-b  6    #considering values for "a" where it meets "b"
a-c  2
b-c  3  #b has the second max TOTAL value
b-b  1
c-d  2  # finally, values in front of c
```

I'd appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: Your 2nd point is not so clear.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to improve it. After finding which element has the maximum value, I'd like to record the values in front of them from max to min.

Comment: It's still not clear. Why is `a-b` 6?

Comment: @NelsonGon if you look at the first two tables, a-b shows the value that a and b cross each other.

Comment: Can you clarify why b-b is 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: adding source data at bottom

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather(col, val, -row) %>%   # Pull into long form, with one row for each row-col
  arrange(row, -val) %>%       # Sort by row and descending value
  filter(val != 0) %>%         # Only keep non-zeros
  unite("row", c("row", "col"))# combine row and col columns

  row val
1 a_b   6
2 a_c   2
3 b_c   3
4 b_a   1
5 c_d   2
```

---

```
# Inputing data with "row" column
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "row  a b c d
a 0 6 2 0
b 1 0 3 0
c 0 0 0 2
d 0 0 0 0 ")
```

Comment: This seems an elegant solution but I received this error while checking your code:
``Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator"
Could you tell me please what I am missing?

Comment: I imported your data from the text you provided and called the first column "row." To make your question simpler to answer, it is good practice to include the output of `dput(YOUR_DATA)` so that we can work with your data in the same form you are. Otherwise, we are left to guess whether your data is in a matrix, a data frame, a data table, with characters, factors, integers, floating point numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely certain, but is this what you want?  You say you have a dataframe but it looks more like you have a matrix and it's not clear if you want to keep your first action or if that's just an intermediate step.

```
mat <- as.matrix(df)

df1 <- data.frame(addmargins(mat, 2))

df1

  a b c d Sum
a 0 6 2 0   8
b 1 0 3 0   4
c 0 0 0 2   2
d 0 0 0 0   0

df2 <- as.data.frame(as.table(mat))

df2 <- df2[df2$Freq != 0,]

df2[with(df2, order(ave(Freq, Var1, FUN = sum), Freq, decreasing = TRUE)), ]

   Var1 Var2 Freq
5     a    b    6
9     a    c    2
10    b    c    3
2     b    a    1
15    c    d    2
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="a b c d
 0 6 2 0
 1 0 3 0
 0 0 0 2
 0 0 0 0", header = TRUE, row.names = letters[1:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

First question is just `rowSums` , for you second I am using `melt` , then order with `groupby` `max` and the value itself

```
s=setNames(reshape2::melt(as.matrix(df)), c('rows', 'vars', 'values'))
s=s[s$values!=0,]
s[order(-ave(s$values,s$rows,FUN=max),-s$values),]
rows vars values
5     a    b      6
9     a    c      2
10    b    c      3
2     b    a      1
15    c    d      2
```